# URL encoding in swift 3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I need to encode the time stamp in my url from 03-28-2017 11:00:05 +0000 to this format 01-01-1970%2000%3A00%3A00%20%2B0530.

I am using this code:

```
updateCheckUrl = updateCheckUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:  NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

But the result is not as expected its just adding %20 in the spaces. 
How can i get the desired encoding using swift 3.1.

Comment: what is your desired encoding ?

Comment: Neither of the default encodings is suitable to encode parameters! You should take the `queryAllowed` and remove `&=+`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "03-28-2017 11:00:05 +0000"
let encode = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) 
print(encode) // 03-28-2017%2011:00:05%20+0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
allowedCharacters.remove(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]")

let paramValue = "03-28-2017 11:00:05 +0000"
let encodedValue = paramValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters) ?? ""
print(encodedValue)
```